# Force cache update for all users

Tags: html, vue.js, cache-control

So, I have a website developed with VueCLI and I know that webpack generates a new hash for my files every time something changes between builds.

But even that occurring, my website is not updating correctly, some people are seeing the old version in their browsers.

In some tests I did using Google Chrome I faced a strange behavior, when I change the files and reload the current tab it gets the last code. But if I close the tab and opens a new one, it gets the old code.

Any idea why this is happening? And how can I solve that, so everyone access the last version of my code?

Comment: is your html file cached?

Comment: I have a rule in my .htaccess setting the cache time of my html files for only 30 seconds

Comment: Sometimes even clearing my browser data makes no difference, I still get the old version

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is caching the page it loaded from your web server (Nginx, Apache...) the first time the user went on your website.

To prevent this, you may want to configure your web server in order to send specific headers.

Ex:
`Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0`

Comment: And where should I put this? In the header of my html?

Comment: No. It is server related. What is your web server ?

Comment: I am using Hostgator

Comment: Hostgator is a host provider. 
You may want to know the name of the web server provided by hostgator. A web server's role is to satisfy web request (eg a call to your site). If you don't have access to the configuration of the webserver, you wont be able to edit the headers.

Comment: Ah, ok.. you mean apache, nginx, etc.? If that is what you mean, then I know we are using Apache